# How can I translate vertex coordinates relative to the 3d cursor's coordinates?

Tags: transforms

When I move a vertex by entering the coordinates in the transform (N-key) it moves relative to (0, 0, 0) in world coordinates regardless if I have "Local" or "Global" active. But I wish to make the 3d cursor's location the (0, 0, 0) origin if that is possible.

Comment: That's not true, local will move relative to the object's origin.

Comment: Indeed it should but all coordinates remain the same for me even in local. Something's up with my blender. But my question was not about how local or global works.

Comment: It will be the same of the objects origin is at the center of the coordinate system.

Comment: Ah, that explains it then. Thanks.

Comment: There is not straight way to do this yet (2.81). Only workarounds. I created a proposal and collected similar requests (with answers), that may also help you: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/yZdbbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the 3D cursor and then with the object selected, use *Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*. When you use *Local* in the *Transform* panel it will now move relative to the position you've set with your 3D cursor. *Local* is always relative to the object's origin, which is indicated by an orange dot when the object is selected in object mode.

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Comment: If I relocate origin my screw modifier changes too.